# Check if this object exists before

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uialertcontroller

In my app, the user is able to add babies names. I want to make sure this baby is not added before, so I can add him. If he is there, an error message appear telling so. 
The problem here, I can't check if this baby is added or not. The code for checking is never executed. I don't know why. 
I tried to figure out the problem in many ways. But when the checking code ecxuted, the alert message appears with a black screen and add the baby any way!

Here is my code, This code saves the baby any way whether is added or not.

```
    let addBaby = PFObject(className: "Baby")

    let CheckBaby = PFQuery(className: "Baby")
    CheckBaby.whereKey("user1", equalTo: ParentID!)
    CheckBaby.whereKey("user2", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    CheckBaby.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object:[PFObject]?,
        error:NSError?) -> Void in

        for object in object! {
            if object["baby_name"] as! String == self.babyName {
                print("This baby has been added before.")
                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Error", message:"This baby has been added before.", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction (title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
                myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return}
            else{
            }
        }// end for
    })

    addBaby.setObject(self.ParentID!, forKey: "user1")
    addBaby.setObject(self.babyName.text!, forKey: "baby_name")
    addBaby.setObject(self.parentName.text!, forKey: "parent_fname")
    addBaby.setObject(self.babyClass.text!, forKey: "class_name")
    addBaby.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!, forKey: "user2")


    addBaby.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (saved:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if saved {
            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        } else {
            error!.localizedDescription
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is adding the baby regardless of the results of the find. Your code basically says this:

```
Create add baby
Find a baby like this
    If there is one like this, display alert
Setup baby to be added
Add the baby
    If it works, popview
```

What you want is:

```
Find a baby like this
    If there is one, display alert
    If there isn't one
         Create baby to add
         Setup baby to be added
         Add the baby
             If it works, pop view
```

Something like:

```
let CheckBaby = PFQuery(className: "Baby")
CheckBaby.whereKey("user1", equalTo: ParentID!)
CheckBaby.whereKey("user2", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
CheckBaby.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object:[PFObject]?,
    error:NSError?) -> Void in

    var babyNotFound = true

    for object in object! {
        if object["baby_name"] as! String == self.babyName {

            babyNotFound = false

            print("This baby has been added before.")
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Error", message:"This baby has been added before.", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction (title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
            myAlert.addAction(okAction)
            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
         }
    }

    if babyNotFound {
        let addBaby = PFObject(className: "Baby")

        addBaby.setObject(self.ParentID!, forKey: "user1")
        addBaby.setObject(self.babyName.text!, forKey: "baby_name")
        addBaby.setObject(self.parentName.text!, forKey: "parent_fname")
        addBaby.setObject(self.babyClass.text!, forKey: "class_name")
        addBaby.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!, forKey: "user2")


        addBaby.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (saved:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if saved {
               self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
            } else {
                error!.localizedDescription
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Note: I have just reorganized your code, it is still in need of readability changes to make it useable in a production application.

There is also the problem of the black dot you described, this is probably happening because you are doing UI code on a background thread. UI updates should be on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    () -> Void in
    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Same problem!! this code is not working and added the baby any way!! if object["baby_name"] as! String == self.babyName {
            babyNotFound = false
            print("This baby has been added before.")
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Error", message:"This baby has been added before.", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction (title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
            myAlert.addAction(okAction)
            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil) return}

Comment: Yaay, it worked!! I tried your suggested solution and dispatch_async func. In addition, I realized I forget to put, self.babyName.text in the comparison.